# Scene changing issue with Timeline in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I am making a simple JavaFX game with a main menu, an options menu, and an actual game. I was able to successfully navigate through all of these menus until I made a seemingly unrelated change: I called the method "runGame()" on the following line.

The scene is getting changed, as I ran the statement

```
if (window.getScene() == app) {
    System.out.println("This is working");
}
```

between window.setScene(app) and the runGame() call. However, even though the scene is apparently changing, it is not shown, and the program becomes unresponsive.

The content of runGame() is as follows:

```
public void runGame() {

        gameClock = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> spawnAndShrink()));
        gameClock.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        // Timer for program
        while (!Target.isGameOver()) {

            gameClock.play();

        }

        gameClock.stop();

    }
```

I have already declared "Timeline gameClock" at the top of my program and imported all the necessary classes. There are no error messages.

I have also modified the runGame() method during my troubleshooting process, changing

```
gameClock = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> spawnAndShrink()));
```

to

```
gameClock = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> System.out.println("Timeline is working")));
```

The method "spawnAndShrink()" is intended to be called every second; it calls two other methods names "spawn()" and "shrink()" (super creative, I know). Did I set up my Timeline wrong, or is there an error in the underlying methods? I also encountered the same error changing scenes when I tried calling "Thread.sleep(1000)" in a while loop instead of using a Timeline.

Comment: Your `while` loop is keeping the _JavaFX Application Thread_ from doing anything else; it just keeps calling `gameClock().play()` over and over.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you so much!